# print statements are not coming on console with logging module

Tags: python, logging

I am using below logging code in unittest module framework

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(output_dir, "w")
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Problem is that when I am having print statements in the code, these are not getting printed anywhere. Not on the console and not in the output file (though I understand why these are not getting printed in file).

Can anybody tell me the reason and solution to print `print` statements on the console
I am using python 2.7

Comment: try this cmd ./python -m test -s where option s will help to print statement on console.

Comment: @Anup: Do you mean  `python -m <fileName> -s` ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting StreamHandler anywhere, modified your example below.

```
import logging
output_dir = "/tmp/somefile"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(output_dir, "w")
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# HERE
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info("test")
logger.info("test")
logger.info("test")
logger.info("test")
```

This gives me both output on console as well as in file.

EDIT:

Not the best idea, agree, but taken straight from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)

```
import logging
import unittest

logger = None

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')
        logger.info(self)
    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

        logger.info(self)
    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

        logger.info(self)

def setup_log():
    global logger
    output_dir = "/tmp/somefile"
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(output_dir, "w")
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.info("Logger ready")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_log()
    unittest.main()
```

It works, so probably you have some other problem in your code, if you update with more elaborate version, perhaps we can help.

Comment: I removed streamHandler. Earlier it was there but print statements were not coming on the console. By the way is it mandatory to have streamHandler ?

Comment: Mandatory no. But if you set only FileHandler, how could it print to console too? This needs to be explicit

Comment: Instead of logger.ingo("test"), if I give `print "test", will it print on the console

Comment: print communicates directly with stdout, that's different

Comment: I read somewhere that unititest python framework turns off stdout and stderr. That is the reason, print statements are not coming on the console

Comment: What kind of unittest? unittest module, pytest, tox? If you update question we can take a look to

Comment: Unittest module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160854/discussion-between-justme-and-nitesh).